window.alert works after clearing cache in safari
I'm building an extension for safari.
I have window.alert in content.js. It works most of the time, but sometimes it doesn't.
When it doesn't work, I clear cache of safari and it starts working again.
I want to make it work all the time without clearing cache.
How can I achieve it?
content.js:
window.addEventListener("load", async (event) => {
  console.log("loading");
  try {
     window.alert("alert");
 }
}
)

I googled but I couldn't find any related questions about this problem.

When it doesn't work, are there any errors in the console? Are you sure your code that calls it is running (add console.log() calls to the code).

Please post the code of a minimal reproducible example.

@Barmar I tried to use web inspector to check error on content.js  but it doesn't show up in develop > my device > safari .

I'm not sure what that is. On my Mac, it's Develop > Show JavaScript Console.

I could solve this error.
The reason why alert was not displayed is because "load" is　not applicable when its from cache. See this.
So I changed from "load" to "pageshow".
My whole code is as below.
window.addEventListener("pageshow", async (event) => {
  console.log("loading");

  if (event.persisted) {
    console.log("displayed from cache");
    window.location.reload();
  } 
})

Then it worked!
